# What's the difference between using observedAttributes() vs MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

With a custom component, you can use the `static get observedAttributes()` in your web component to specify what attribute changes trigger the `attributeChangedCallback()` lifecycle method.

However, it seems you can also achieve a similar callback by using the `MutationObserver` API, [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe), with `{attributes: true}` to watch all attribute changes, or to refine it more, using a `{attributeFilter: Array<string>}`.

What's the difference in using the two different methods? Seems like the MutationObserver offer much more flexibility, while the first method is equivalent to having defined an attribute filter.

Comment: Yes, minor functional differences. But MO takes a lot more boilerplate, and you can't ask the MO _which_ attributes are observed. It is kinda like saying _Why do we need Map, when everything can be done by extending Array_ I don't have data, but would say ``observedAttributes`` is highly optimized. MO is taking a sledgehammer to drive in a nail.

Comment: Ok, thanks. `observedAttributes` is called before the constructor is called, so that made it hard to programmatically set what attributes are watched in the constructor. Seems like I'd have to take the sledgehammer approach. Happy to accept this as answer if you put it there!#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, minor functional differences.

But MutationObserver takes a lot more boilerplate, and you can't ask the MO which attributes are observed.

It is kinda like saying Why do we need Map, when everything can be done by extending Array

I don't have data, but would say `observedAttributes` is highly optimized. MO is taking a sledgehammer to drive in a nail.

But as you commented; `observedAttributes` doesn't give you dynamic attributes.